# Check for duplicate values for ip address (user input) using hashmap in java

Tags: java, string, collections, hashmap, java.util.scanner

Main class to enter all the domain details like Domain name and ip address. I need to check for duplicate values entered for ip address. I need a code for hashmap to check for duplicate values.
Input would be     [www.gmail.net](http://www.gmail.net)    195.116.254.154
output would be like - if the ipAddress is 195.116.254.154 the output should be [www.gmail.net](http://www.gmail.net)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        DomainBO dBO = new DomainBO();
        Map<String, String> domainMap = new HashMap<>();
        dBO.setDomainMap(domainMap);
        String ip, Dname;
        int flag = 0;
        int input;
        int count = 0;
        String DomainName = null;
        do {
            System.out.println("1. Add DNS details");
            System.out.println("2. Find matching Domain Name");
            System.out.println("3. Exit");
            System.out.println("Enter your choice");
            input = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            if (input == 1) {
                count++;
                System.out.println("Enter the domain name");
                Dname = sc.nextLine();
                 
                System.out.println("Enter the IP address");
                ip = sc.nextLine();
                if (isValid(Dname) || IPAddressValidator(ip))// check for valid ipaddress and name
                {
                dBO.addDNSDetails(Dname, ip);
                flag = 0;
                }
                else
                    flag = 0 ;
                
            }
            if (input == 2) {
                if (count > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Enter the IP address to find the domain name");
                    ip = sc.nextLine();
                    DomainName = dBO.findDomainName(ip);
                    if (DomainName == null) {
                        System.out.println("No matching domain name found");
                        flag = 0;

                    } else {
                        System.out.println(DomainName);
                        flag = 0;
                    }
                }

            }

            if (input == 3) {
                System.out.println("Thank you for using the Application");
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        } while (flag == 0);

    }
```

The DomainBO.java class is used to enter domain details and retrieve the domain name by inputting Ipaddress.

```
public class DomainBO {
private Map<String,String> domainMap;
    
    
    public Map<String,String> getDomainMap() {
        return domainMap;
    }


    public void setDomainMap(Map<String,String> domainMap) {
        this.domainMap = domainMap;
    }


    //This method should add the domainName as key and their ipAddress as value into a Map
    public void addDNSDetails  (String domainName,String ipAddress)
    {   
        
            if(domainMap.containsKey(ipAddress)) 
            {
                return;
                        }
            else
            {
                domainMap.put(domainName, ipAddress); 
            }
       
    }
    

    public String findDomainName(String ipAddress) {
        
      String domain=null;
        
        if(domainMap.isEmpty()){
        return domain;
        }
        else
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : domainMap.entrySet()) {
            String k = entry.getKey();
            String v = entry.getValue(); 
            
            if (ipAddress.equals(v)) {
                domain = k;                 
            }
            else
            {
                domain = "No matching domain name found";
                
            }
     }     
 

    
    return domain;
}
```

}

Comment: Whats your problem? You already check if there are already listings with .containsKey(ipAddress)

Comment: You need to ask a question.

Comment: i have no code for checking duplicate values.. my code is accepting duplicate ip address values

Comment: And also if i add more than one domain values it shows only the recent added one. The first one added is not getting displayed

Answer (score 1):

You say that you want to map domainName to ip addr. but you check for domainMap.containsKey(ipAddress). That is not right because your keys are domain names, not ip addresses.

You can use a code like this to check for duplicates in values(ip addr.) if that is what you need

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> set : domainMap.entrySet()) {
      if (set.getValue().equals(currentIp)) 
         System.out.println("Duplicate ip"); // Do whatever you want in here
}
```

Comment: where should i add this method? in main class ??

Answer (score 0):

In the addDNSDetails method you've written

```
domainMap.put(domainName, ipAddress);
```

The first parameter is the key used to find the data, the second parameter is the value. You're putting the domain name as the key, but by your description want to use the IP address to find the domain, not the other way around. So change this code to:

```
domainMap.put(ipAddress, domainName);
```

Comment: for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : domainMap.entrySet()) {
            String k = entry.getKey();
            String v = entry.getValue(); 
            
            if (ipAddress.equals(v)) {
                domain = k;                 
            }
            else
            {
                domain = "No matching domain name found";
                
            }
     }

Comment: This code is not giving me data when i try to retrieve data second time. 1. I enter domain name and ip address 2. again i enter DN and Ip 3. I search for 1st ip its gives correct result. 4. When i search for 2nd ip it says domain name not found

Comment: I am not sure why my loop is not giving correct result?

Comment: Could you edit the question and include your current code and the problems youres having with it? Or post a new question, very few people read questions thst are two days old. Code in comments is unreadable.